# DB back up year wise and hold only last two calendar years data only

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database has 8 years of data and the code is taking some time to retrieve the data. I am planning to hold only last two years of data and the remaining data will be moved to temporary tables. For example employee table has last 8 years data so I want to create `employee2013`, `emploee2014` and corresponding year data will moved to these tables.

Guide me how to do this and is this approach is correct or give me any better idea.
I am using SQL Server 2014 and have 300 tables with with hundreds of thousands of rows

Comment: in brief : 1. create new table. 2. insert into new table. 3. delete from old table

Comment: Thanks any other way than this because It is too complex, have 300 tables with multiple relationship keys are there. Is there any easy way like generate script from the database.

Comment: Using Indian words like "lac" will definitely cause confusion. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Huh?  Why would you move older data to *temporary* tables.  Those are deleted periodically.

In any case, it seems like you want to separate data out by years.  This is called "partitioning".  This is a broad topic, so you should start to learn about it from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017).

Once you have partitions, you can physically keep only the most recent two years by dropping older partitions or moving them to new tables.  However, that might not be necessary.  You can just create a view that accesses the two most recent years and have users access the views.

You don't specify *why* you want to do this.  If the reason is just performance, then multiple tables is definitely not the right solution.  In fact, for most purposes, a combination of partitions and indexes is probably the way to go.